# Magento 2: Shopping Cart quantity doesnt update after custom Add to cart form is submitted

Tags: magento2, checkout, phtml, shopping-cart, bundled-product

I have a custom `Add to Cart` button for **bundled** products. 
This is on my phtml for the `/test-page` :

```
<?php
/** @var Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $_checkoutCartHelper */
$_checkoutCartHelper = $this->helper(Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart::class);
/** @var Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product */
$postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>

<form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_checkoutCartHelper->getAddUrl($_product); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey');

    /** @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection $selection */
    foreach ($block->getSelectionCollection($_product) as $selection) {       
        echo '<input type="hidden" aria-required="true" name="bundle_option['
            . $selection->getOptionId() . ']" class="bundle-option-' . $selection->getOptionId() . ' product bundle option" value="'
            . $selection->getSelectionId() . '" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="bundle_option_qty['
            . $selection->getOptionId() . ']" value="'
            . $selection->getSelectionQty() . '" />';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" value="1"/>
    <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick=" this.form.submit()"
            title="<?= $_customProductHelper->getAddToCartText($_product, 'Add to Cart') ?>">
            <span><span>
                    <?php echo $_customProductHelper->getAddToCartText($_product, 'Add to Cart') ?>
            </span></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

It works fine; after the user clicks on *Add to Cart*, the bundle product is added to the shopping cart and then it is redirected back to the `/test-page`. It then appears the message  "You added TEST Bundle Product to your shopping cart."

**The problem is that the little shopping cart on the corner doesn't update the quantity of the products with the recent added-to-cart product.**

[image]

However, if I go to `/checkout/cart`, the product is there.

Any ideas why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: UPDATE: in the browser console, found out that the request to update the shopping cart ( /customer/section/load/?sections=cart%2Cdirectory-data%2Cmessages&force_new_section_timestamp=false&_=1591330266201 )
is not called. Should I add it manually? Isnt it executed automatically with the checkout/cart/add action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some hours debugging, found out that the way the form was submitted was the problem.
I had this line:

```
<button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick=" this.form.submit()"
```

When I had to have:

```
<button type="submit"
```

However, I don't know why that makes a difference.

Anyways, that is now updating the mini cart!